# Enterprise Java Beans

Tags: class, javabeans, enterprise

I have a question about Enterprise Java Beans.

Every enterprise bean requires the following code:

•   Remote interface

•   Home interface

•   Enterprise bean class

A remote interface defines the business methods that a client may call. Business methods are implemented in the enterprise bean code.

A home interface defines methods that allow a client to create, find, or remove an enterprise bean.

Can I please have an easy to understand description about what the Enterprise bean class does?

Answer (score 0):

Enterprise Beans are intended to provide encapsulated business logic for enterprise applications within a general container that provided things like session management, security, resource pooling, etc. as services thus allowing the business logic to be (relatively) untainted by these cross-cutting concerns.

Enterprise Beans are simply a class with your business logic which is managed by the EJB container.